# Why is my padding not working in my footer bar?

Tags: html, css, padding

I don't understand why my top and bottom padding is not zero? The border around the text has a padding of zero so why is it so far away from the text? see the image:

[image]

```css
footer {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.footertable {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin: 0%;
}

.footertext {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <ul class="footertable">
    <li class="footertext">
      <p>footer</p>
    </li>
    <li class="footertext">
      <p>footer</p>
    </li>
    <li class="footertext">
      <p>footer</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Comment: default margins of the <p>. `.footertext p { margin: 0; }`  will solve it

Comment: This worked. Thank You!